# setup remote desktop without gui

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a computer running ubuntu that I want to be able to remotely access. Is there a way to set this up using only the terminal? if so, can you provide step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

you can connect your computer(With ubuntu running on it) to remote computer(With ubuntu running on it) using ssh...

Requirements :

```
1) Remote computer User name & IP address.
2) Password of remote computer user.
```

Follow following steps :

1) Open terminal.(Ctrl+Alt+T).
   2) Enter command :
       a)To install ssh :

```
      sudo apt-get install ssh 

   b)If already installed ,to start ssh service :

     sudo service ssh start

      To see ssh service status :

       sudo service ssh status

   c)To connect to remote Computer with username & IP known

       ssh username@IP_Address 

  Then Enter password of remote Computer.
```

3)After Performing these steps ,you will be in remote computer terminal...now you can do

whatever you want with(copy,delete,shutdown) your remote computer.

---

If you want to copy remote computer data without connecting you can use scp command...

IF u want more help regarding this u can ask....